# Sum of two elements in a vector

Tags: r

I want to perform the following easy calculation for an example data

```
a<-seq(1:10)
```

Now, is there an built-in function,, which returns a vector: `(a[1]+a[2],a[3]+a[4],...,a[9]+a[10])`. Note I'm able to implement this using a for loop or using `rollapply` (and deleting some elements). However, I'm wondering if there is a built-in function I do not know so far.

Comment: For such cases, perhaps see "tricks" like `colSums(matrix(a, nrow = 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rollapply` in the zoo package can do that in a straightforward manner:

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(a, 2, by = 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
a[c(T,F)] + a[c(F,T)]
```